# Include NA after removing outliers

Tags: r, na, outliers

I want to include NAs in my dataset after removing outliers. For example, in the dataframe below I want to remove outliers > 13. I have subsetted by dataframe to create new one without the outliers but my code has also removed NAs. I have tried using na.rm= FALSE but I am only getting an error for it.

```
id <- c(3,3,6,6,4,4,3,3)
age_cat <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,)
measurement <- c(10, 13, 14,13, NA, 11, NA, 17)
myData <- data.frame(id, age_cat, measurement)
myData

#If I use this the outliers are removed along with NAs
myData_no_ol <- subset(myData, myData$measurement < 13)
myData_no_ol

#If I use this I get an error
#Error: unexpected ',' in "myData_no_ol <- subset((myData,"

myData_no_ol <- subset((myData, myData$measurement < 13), na.rm= FALSE)
myData_no_ol
```

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Thanks!
P

Comment: You have `3,)`in the `age_cat`.  `subset`, `filter` removes the `NA` in the logical vector.  if there is any `NA`, it returns `NA` for that comparison.

Comment: `myData_no_ol <- subset(myData, myData$measurement < 13 | is.na(myData$measurement))` can help you!

Comment: When you run this code, either line-by-line or by sourcing the whole document, you should not ignore errors or warnings. In this case, per @akrun's comment, you should have seen `Error in c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ) : argument 9 is empty`, a clear indicator that something is just *wrong*, and any follow-on code (or warnings/errors from it) is suspect at best.

Comment: Thanks for noting that error. However, I am getting the same error even after correcting for it. I wonder if using na.rm= FALSE is not the right thing and why would it still give me a syntax error. Having said that, @Duck's code using is.na worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add a clause for is.na(). Since R will return NA instead of T or F when asking is NA < 13

```
myData_no_ol <- subset(myData, myData$measurement < 13 | is.na(myData$measurement))
```